# Can subversion be hosted on Amazon's hosted cloud service?

Tags: svn, amazon-ec2

Can subversion be hosted on Amazon's hosted cloud service?

Comment: But is will cost more then most svn hosting companies, so if you don't need complete control over  your svn install, I would not do it

Comment: I'm not sure that the above comment is true anymore in 2012, with the free tier pricing on Micro instances.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Sure. Set up an ec2 instance with linux and install svn on that server.

Answer (score 13):

Absolutely - my company hosts a public open source SVN repository and our private repository on an Amazon EC2 instance.  You'll want to be careful about data integrity and backups; we store the repository data on an Elastic Block Store volume for resilience, svnsync the repositories to another EC2 instance and EBS volume so that we can quickly bring up a new SVN server if the main one goes down, and also do an offsite backup via svnadmin dump to one of our physical servers just in case the whole cloud goes offline (hey, our source code is our crown jewels after all !)

The only other thing I can think of is that Amazon isn't particularly up to date with the Linux versions that they provide.  We run Fedora Core, and the latest version available on EC2 is Fedora Core 8.  The version of SVN that's installed via yum on FC8 is only 1.4.2.2, so if you want a newer version like 1.5 you may have to compile it from source.

Comment: +1 interesting. But is there an advantage (e.g. cost, performance, reliability) over more traditional hosting services? Using two independent hosting services (one main, one backup) seems safer and cheaper at first glance.

Comment: It depends on your hosting company; Amazon has just introduced "reserved instance" pricing, which really cuts down the cost for a long running instance such as an SVN server.  Even with the old pricing, we were saving about half the amount of money we'd previously been paying to Rackspace.

Answer (score 5):

Use amazon's free tier and host your subversion for... wait for it... free!

http://aws.amazon.com/free/

NB: This is limited to 12 mos., and only for new AWS users.

Answer (score 4):

Get a reserved instance at ec2 if you plan on using it for at least a year.

On a one year contract you pay $227.50 + $0.03/hr for a default instance, and on a three year contract it's $350 + $0.03/hr.

If you were to keep them running full time:

- (0.03*24*365 + 227.50) / 12 = 40.86 / month for 1yr contract
- (0.03*24*365*3 + 350) / 36  = 31.62 / month for 3yr contract

For full details of the various instance options see http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/#pricing

Answer (score 1):

With Amazon's new "Heavy Utilization Reserved Instance" the hourly price is down to $0.005 for a micro instance and $0.02 for a small instance. Both are adequate for SVN.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't EC2 cost about $0.10/minute to keep your server up?  (That's what it cost a year ago, the last time I checked.)  There are other hosted subversion options that cost significantly less.  I used to use cvsdude for about $5-10/month.

Comment: The mininum full price for an EC2 instance is 10c / hour, but you can halve that with Amazon's new "reserved pricing".  Still more than cvsdude or some of the traditional hosting services, but worth it for us to get full control over the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the hosted [Indefero](http://www.indefero.net) offer. It will cost you $0.007/hour (£49/year). So cheaper than EC2. The day you want to get your own server, you just download all your data, load that in your server, change your DNS entry and go.

As you have the full data export, your forge is under your own domain and Indefero is GPL software, you have no vendor lock-in effect.

Answer (score 0):

Sure it can. There is ready to go/install image available [here](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B007I9FYWU/ref=ads_4281933e-b029-1456146651).

If you want to use Git, AWS has [CodeCommit](https://aws.amazon.com/codecommit/).